# Is it possible to have a per-domain custom log with VirtualHost and Rewrite Rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

In apache I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    CustomLog /private/var/log/apache2/access_log vcommon
    ErrorLog /private/var/log/apache2/error_log
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /%2/$1
    ServerName "%-2.0.%-1.0"
    ServerAlias "www.%-2.0.%-1.0"    
</VirtualHost>
```

And in the /Library/WebServer/Documents directory I have folders for each domain, i.e:

```
thisdomain.com
thatdomain.com
anotherdomain.net
```

The server all works and serves the correct files per domain, But I'm trying to create separate log files for each domain as well, i.e:

```
thisdomain.com-access.log
thisdomain.com-error.log
thatdomain.com-access.log
thatdomain.com-error.log
```

Is it possible to use the output from the rewrite rule as a filename for the CustomLog and ErrorLog directives? Something like:

```
CustomLog /private/var/log/apache2/"%-2.0.%-1.0"-access_log vcommon
ErrorLog /private/var/log/apache2/"%-2.0.%-1.0"error_log
```

If not is there some other way of making apache create per-domain log files?